# Push on a ComboBox using WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, push

I have a combobox in a WPF Window, it is filled with usernames from database,

When  a new user is created in database, i want the UserName to be pushed to the ComboBox, i.e., added to the existing.

Similary when a User is deleted, it should be Poped from the `ComboBox`.

How can i do this.
Currently, i am using `WPF MVVM` with `Caliburn Micro`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bind the ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection for that.  Works when you add or delete items from the collection.

Comment: yes, push: `myStack.Insert(0, item);`, pop: `var item = myStack[0]; myStack.RemoveAt[0];`

Comment: No, i am using MVVM, so i create a user from other window(viewmodel), and when a User is added to database, it should be added to mainviewmodel

Comment: So you're not asking about combos, you're asking how the database can provide push notifications of adds to the application? It can't. You'll need to implement that yourself somehow (eg polling in MainViewModel)

Comment: I'm using MVVM also - that has nothing to do with it.  GazTheDestroyer is right.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `MVVM` then you should have some collection that is bound to `ComboBox.ItemsSource` property. If any changes to collection were made - invoke `FireProeprtyChanged("UsersCollection")`. UI should reflect on this and update `ComboBox`.

***Update:***

If you want to provide some kind of push notifications - you have to create HTTP Polling Duplex WCF Service. Nice example of its implementation by Dan Wahlin: [Syncing Data with a Server using Silverlight and HTTP Polling Duplex](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2011/02/06/syncing-data-with-a-server-using-silverlight-and-http-polling-duplex.aspx)

Comment: i want to fire the property change from other viewmodel